# Using DISTINCT inner join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have two tables T1 & T2 my tables look something like this

```
T1 [ID, AppKey, CommenterKey, Comment, NoteTime]
T2 [ID, UserKey, Firstname, Lastname]
```

on T2 UserKey is correlated to CommenterKey

I would like to join these two tables while filtering the duplicate Comments on the Comments Column per each unique AppKey

Any ideas on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

This is the sample data:

[image]

The idea here is to filter the duplicate comments pertaining to a certain appkey if you look at row 11-15 in the Appkey column it is the same appkey if you look at row 11-15 it is the same comment I want to filter these comments out so the query doesn't return these duplicate rows.

Below is the query I used

```
SELECT Notes.Appkey,
        Notes.CommenterKey,
        Notes.Comment,
        Notes.NoteTime,
        Users.Firstname,
        Users.Lastname
FROM tblNotes AS Notes 
inner join
tblUsers AS Users ON Commenterkey = UserKey
```

Comment: Edit the question Add sample data & desired result.

Comment: First of all. Why a comment can duplicate? If any of comments can duplicate then your table is very likely not correctly normalised. In this case you don't need to use distinct. Otherwise if such duplicates makes sense then you should ask yourself why would you like to use distinct?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: When you say duplicate comments , what is the values for  ID , CommenterKey, NoteTime ?  Are they also having duplicate values ?

Comment: In your case you can't do that. Because the other fields, AppKey, CommenterKey, names ... are not duplicating. How do you proceed with the fields that are not duplicating?

Comment: @armaedescu the duplicate inputs are pulled from a major banking corporation not my own i have no say on how they run it i was thinking to use distinct cause that is what makes most sense to me if you have a better way of doing this i'm all ears i tried to filter the comments using JS in my code but that's not efficient  its making my site run very slow

Comment: @armagedescu names are duplicating and so are appkey and commenterkey

Comment: @PantojaDev The question remains the same. There are other fields duplicating, not only the comments. How exactly would you proceed with these fields to eliminate duplications? The other thing that I see, there are comments like 'Test', 'Comment', 'Comment 1', 'Duplicate'. Is that from a major banking corporation?

Comment: @armagedescu yea the other fields are duplicating everything but the NoteTime field duplicates.... that is from my test environment i don't think putting social securities and peoples  personal info on here was a smart move  bank of america would have my head on a stick if i did so

Comment: @PantojaDev As I see in your sample resultset the NoteTime is not duplicated. Sort by Comment and NoteTime, it does not seem to be duplicated. What exactly you are trying to do? Some statistics by comments? If you are not doing that, then the distinct comments do not make sense. These are different comments, even if they are identical. You should keep in mind what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: No that is NOT the query that generated that resultset. NoteKey is in your image but not in your query. Perhaps you join on the wrong columns? Because it seems NoteKey is likely the PK of Note and there are duplicate rows in Note. But you don't post DDL so we can't know what constraints actually exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data is rather hard to read.  However, you can use `row_number()` or aggregation.  I think this does what you want:

```
select un.*
from (select n.Appkey, n.CommenterKey, n.Comment, n.NoteTime,
             u.Firstname, u.Lastname,
             row_number() over (partition by u.UserKey, n.Comment order by u.UserKey) as seqnum
      from tblNotes n inner join
           tblUsers u 
           on n.Commenterkey = u.UserKey
     ) un
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data, something like this should work.

```
select  n.NoteKey,
        n.AppKey,
        n.CommenterKey,
        n.Comment,
        u.Firstname,
        u.Lastname
from    Notes n
cross apply (
    select  AppKey,
            CommenterKey,
            Comment,
            max(NoteTime) as NoteTime
    from    Notes n2
    where   n.AppKey        = n2.AppKey
    and     n.CommenterKey  = n2.CommenterKey
    and     n.Comment       = n2.Comment
    group by 
            n2.AppKey,
            n2.CommenterKey,
            n2.Comment
) ni 
join    Users u ON u.UserKey = n.CommenterKey
where   ni.NoteTime = n.NoteTime
```

Your biggest issues is probably going to be performance. You may want to consider adding a duplicate flag and either checking via a trigger, or scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CTE Table. Below link is introduction about CTE Table and How to use it

https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/

I think this does what you want,

```
with cte as 
(
        select notes.Appkey as appKey, notes.CommenterKey as CommenterKey, notes.Comment as Comment, notes.NoteTime as NoteTime,
             users.Firstname as Firstname, users.Lastname as Lastname,
             row_number() over (partition by users.UserKey, notes.Comment order by users.UserKey) as sequenceNo
      from tblNotes as notes inner join
           tblUsers as users 
           on notes.Commenterkey = users.UserKey
)

select * from cte where sequenceNo = 1;
```